# https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users - user not available

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I noticed weird behavior. After I added external user via graph api, user is not available in response from graph api but visible on azure active directory.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users - not appear

But if I copy Object ID from azure and get user with that id I have response.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{object-id}

Looks that graph api is unsync with azure and response is out of date. Is there any way to request for restore/refresh cache?

Comment: How long your two request interval is? Some users require additional time to take effect.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question, as it stands today, doesn't include any code examples or examples of the response(s) you are getting back.

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ doesn't return all the users. You can use @odata.nextlink in the response to request next page of users.